# angularjs - refreshing child state view cause lose of data from the parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following ui-router states.

```
.state('admin.userView', {
  abstract:true,
  url:'/user/:id/',
  templateUrl:'./views/user/view.html',
  controller:'userViewController'
})

.state('admin.userView.home', {
  url:'',
  templateUrl:'./views/user/home.html',
  controller:'userHomeController'
})
```

I have fetched user details using http resource in userViewController to $scope.users.
When i move to the admin.userView.home state, I can access the $scope.users .
But when i refresh page with child state, the value in the $scope.users is lost.
How can i get the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving that data into the resolve property of the `admin.userView` state declaration. Since you're using nested resolves here you can then inject that resolved data into the `admin.userView.home` state declaration. Here's an excerpt from the ui-router documentation.

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      resolve:{
         resA:  function(){
            return {'value': 'A'};
         }
      },
      controller: function($scope, resA){
          $scope.resA = resA.value;
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      resolve:{
         resB: function(resA){
            return {'value': resA.value + 'B'};
         }
      },
      controller: function($scope, resA, resB){
          $scope.resA2 = resA.value;
          $scope.resB = resB.value;
      }
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)