# scope variable change after refresh

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In the parent view I request a json file and put it in `$scope.data`. In a child view I can access it without problem and `$scope.data.length` gives me the correct number of items.In the console I can see the json file and it start directly with `[Resource { name="alex...`

 But if I refresh the page, or try to access the child view directly, `$scope.data.length` return '0' but I still can see the json file in `$scope.data`. But it's strange, In the console I don't see it like before anymore, it looks different [image]

console.log($scope.data.length);
console.log($scope.data);

```
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
    {
       if($scope.data[i].id) == $scope.id) 
       {
        selected=$scope.data[i];
        console.log("id found: "+ $scope.id);


        }
    }
```

if I refresh the page, scope.lenght return 0 but in both cases I can see the json file

Comment: Please share your code instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs - refreshing child state view cause lose of data from the parent state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653821/angularjs-refreshing-child-state-view-cause-lose-of-data-from-the-parent-state)

Comment: I don't lose the data, maybe the object type change ...?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273780/fetching-json-data-in-the-controller